# Use a straight voltage line only for a single component in a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I would like to have two different styles of voltage arrows in a single tikzpicture (`europeanvoltages` and `straightvoltages`).

You can use the parameters

```
\ctikzset{voltage/distance from node=0}% in \pgf@circ@Rlen units
\ctikzset{voltage/distance from line=.0}% pos. between 0 and 1
\ctikzset{voltage/bump b/.initial=0.0}%
```

but this is cumbursome for many different arrows. Is there any way to do this more easily?

Here is the MWE (I want the arrow for U_out to be straight):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.arrows,calc,circuits.ee.IEC,calc,datavisualization,datavisualization.polar,math,patterns,datavisualization.formats.functions,external,backgrounds,spy}
\usepackage[compatibility,EFvoltages,european,fetbodydiode]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (0,0) to [*L,-o,v^=$U_\mathrm{L}$] ++ (2.2,0) coordinate(endPos);

    \draw (0,-2) coordinate(uocvmin) to [*C,-] (0,0);

    \draw (uocvmin) to [*short,-o] (uocvmin -| endPos);

    \draw (endPos) to [*open,v=$U_\mathrm{out}$] ++(0,-2); %Arrow that should be straight

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which looks like this:

[image]

and with `straightvoltages`:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not in the manual, because it was experimental (and the interface names are sub-optimal, so they can change in the future) but you can do

```latex
   \draw (endPos) to [*open,v=$U_\mathrm{out}$, straight=true] ++(0,-2);
```

to obtain:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a scope for temporary parameter changes.  Interestingly, straight voltages are not set using `\ctikzset`, although one could always create a `/.code` key.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.arrows,calc,circuits.ee.IEC,calc,datavisualization,datavisualization.polar,math,patterns,datavisualization.formats.functions,external,backgrounds,spy}
\usepackage[compatibility,EFvoltages,european,fetbodydiode]{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\straightV}{\pgf@circuit@bipole@voltage@straighttrue}
\newcommand{\curveV}{\pgf@circuit@bipole@voltage@straightfalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (0,0) to [*L,-o,v^=$U_\mathrm{L}$] ++ (2.2,0) coordinate(endPos);

    \draw (0,-2) coordinate(uocvmin) to [*C,-] (0,0);

    \draw (uocvmin) to [*short,-o] (uocvmin -| endPos);

  \begin{scope}
    \straightV
    \draw (endPos) to [*open,v=$U_\mathrm{out}$] ++(0,-2); %Arrow that should be straight
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```